# Organic Groups - How to view articles in the context of the group

Tags: organic-groups

I have OG setup on a site I am developing. The configuration is set to remove the main sites side bars when a Group is viewed. If an article that is only published in that group is viewed, it is opened in the context of the main Drupal site (All side bars are visible from the main site)

Is there a way to view the article so that it appears the user feels they are still in the group?

Comment: What mechanism did you use to remove the main site's sidebars? Block configuration, theming or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust Group context detection at admin/config/group/context when you have Organic groups context enabled. This will add the appropriate css classes in the body element, which will allow you to theme the rest of the page.

Comment: Thanks for posting that admin URL for Context settings. I have another context-related issue and don't see a link to the OG context settings anywhere.